# change cached exchange mode from office 365 admin center or using PowerShell?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, office365

How to change cached exchange mode to download email to an outlook data file from office 365 admin center or using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn on cached exchange mode in your exchange account using powershell you have to change a registry key:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\cached mode" -Name enable -Value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as now, we can only set this via client side and I'm afraid there is no setting in server side.